# confused with "ような" specific sentence structure

Tags: grammar, ambiguity

I was watching "岡田斗司夫" and then this sentence came out:

> 若し一般人が適用される様な厳しいルールなんだったらローガンポールのYoutubeアカウントだって削除しろよ

I am actually stuck on understanding the meaning of "ような" in this sentence because of the sentence structure. I don't know if it's one of those two meanings:

> ようだ
> （１）不確かな断定の意を表す。「病気で入院していたので，だいぶ仕事がたまっている〈ようだ〉」「足にけがをしたというが，大したこともない〈ようだ〉」
> （４）同類中の一例として提示する意を表す。「あの富士山の〈ような〉形の山が羊蹄山です」「田舎のおばさんの〈ように〉小柄な人」

Answer (score 1):

I think this 「ような」 means 「２ 例示の意を表す。「隣のおばさんのような働き者は少ない」」 of https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%A0 . Because 一般人が適用される is an example of 厳しいルール in this case.